# Dynamic fields and slow queries

Tags: performance, indexing, mongodb

Currently, I'm managing a set of lists containing a number of members.
Every list can look different, when it comes to fields and the naming of these fields.

Typically, a basic list member could look like so (from my members collection):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52284ae408edcb146200009f"),
    "list_id" : 1,
    "status" : "active",
    "imported" : 1,
    "fields" : {
        "firstname" : "John",
        "lastname" : "Doe",
        "email" : "john@example.com",
        "birthdate" : ISODate("1977-09-03T23:08:20.000Z"),
        "favorite_color" : "Green",
        "interests" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 8,
                "value" : "Books"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 10,
                "value" : "Travel"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 12,
                "value" : "Cooking"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 15,
                "value" : "Wellnes"
            }
        ]
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2012-05-06T15:12:26.000Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-05-06T15:12:26.000Z")
}
```

All the fields under the "fields" index, is fields that is unique for the current list id - and these fields can change for every list ID, which means a new list could look like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52284ae408edcb146200009f"),
    "list_id" : 2,
    "status" : "active",
    "imported" : 1,
    "fields" : {
        "fullname" : "John Doe",
        "email" : "john@example.com",
        "cell" : 123456787984
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2012-05-06T15:12:26.000Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-05-06T15:12:26.000Z")
}
```

Currently, my application is allowing users to search dynamically in each of the customs fields, but since they have no indexes, this process can be very slow.

I don't believe it's an option to allow list creaters to select which fields should be indexed - but I really need to speed this up.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your documents in a way that you have an array of fields, you can leverage indexes.

```
fields: [
    { name: 'fullName', value: 'John Doe' },
    { name: 'email', value: 'john@example.com' },
    ...
]
```

Create an index on fields.name and fields.value.

Of course this is not a solution for "deeper" values like your interests list.